# How to get rid of a WPF Datagrid extra space (row?) at the bottom?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, row, space

I have this datagrid, and sometimes it'll show that horrible gray space at the bottom, it doesn't even seem to have a pattern to show... Sometimes it's there, sometimes it's not.
I've tried CanUserAddRows to false and it does not fix it.
It's not an extra item in my collection either, I just checked that with the debugger.
I really need to remove that behavior, any ideas?

[image: DataGridExtraSpace]

```
<DataGrid x:Name="NotesDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Notes, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0" Height="Auto" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" 
                  GridLinesVisibility="All" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFF7F7F7" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFF7F7F7" Padding="0"
                  AlternatingRowBackground="#FFFBFBFB" ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource dgColumnHeaderStyle}" CellStyle="{DynamicResource dgCellStyle}" RowStyle="{DynamicResource dgRowStyle}" LostFocus="NotesDataGrid_LostFocus">
```

Comment: None of the solutions is working  :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting DataGrid.Background to white ?

Comment: This doesn't work for me cause I have a button exactly under this datagrid, and I don't want the user to see the button strangely moving around...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was caused by the `DataGrid`'s `MaxHeight` property not being set to a multiple of the row size, so the left over space was showing up at the bottom of the `DataGrid`. For example: if there are 5 rows that are 10 pixels in height and the `MaxHeight` property is set to 55 then there will be 5 pixels of space at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your DataGrid in Grid and try `DataGrid.VerticalAlignment="Top"`

```
  <Grid><DataGrid VerticalAlignment="Top" ... /></Grid>
```

Comment: yeah I just tried that one too, and it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: At least I found out what causes the space is a change in the DataContext type, those notes are for various object types, if I move between objects of the same kind it doesn't resize, but whenever I move to a different type it shows the horrible gray row...

Answer (score 0):

I know it's long time since the question was asked. But anyway I had the same problem and I could fix it by setting a property of the Datagrid.

```
IsReadOnly="True"
```